# How does an opaque context come about in adverbials?

Tags: semantics, adverbs

I cannot get my head around examples (19) and (20) in Maienborn & Schäfer (2011) (in v. Heusinger, Maienborn & Portner (eds), HSK 33.2). How is it that *necessarily* (as an epistemic adverbial) creates opaque contexts for both subject and object:

> (19) a. Necessarily, nine is an odd number. 
> b. The number of planets is nine.
> c. ↛ Necessarily, the number of planets is an odd number.

> (20) a. Necessarily, nine is an odd number.
> b. Nine is a lucky number.
> c. ↛ Necessarily, nine is a lucky number.

Similarly, I don't see what's going on with *intentionally* in M&S's (31) (taken from (Thomason & Stalnaker (1973)) creating an opaque context for the object position but not for the subject position:

> (31) Oedipus intentionally married Jocasta.
> a. Oedipus is the son of Laius. → The son of Laius intentionally married Jocasta.
> b. Jocasta is Oedipus’ mother. ↛ Oedipus intentionally married his mother.

I understand how *believes* in *Mary believes that Cicero is a great orator* creates an opaque context and that it does not have the same truth conditions as *Mary believes that Tully is a great orator* (Tully being a nickname for Cicero). That's because Mary might not know that Tully and Cicero are co-referential. The way I understand it, we don't know Mary's knowledge state and thus we cannot consider the Cicero and the the Tully propositions to have identical truth conditions. I just cannot get my head around this for (19) and (29). Any help in breaking this apart would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Ok, so I understand how (31) works: The fact that two different expressions (that are coreferential) are used in (31a) is inconsequential as it is the intentions of 'Oedipus' and 'the son of Laius' exactly overlap. However, 'Jocasta' and 'his mother' create a problem as we must assume that Oedipus did not know/might not have know that 'his mother' = 'Jocasta: He might have different intentions for Jocasta than for his mother. Is that right?
(I still don't get (19) and (20).)

Comment: None of the examples have objects; they're intransitive. What are you asking about?